# PHP: Email headers

Tags: php, email, html-email

I am sending email through PHP and I want to change the "sent by" email in the headers:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: test@test.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: test@test.com' . "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

I am also attaching the image for reference:
[image]
I want to change the highlighted email address. Thanks in advance

Comment: In your connection to your SMTP server, what account are you using?

Comment: Where to check it I am simply using the mail() function of PHP. Can you guide me where to check that.

Comment: In your `php.ini` file. [Read the documentation of the config values](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php).

Comment: The image is circumstantial evidence at best.  Show the actual headers from the message's source.  Chances are you have an envelope sender which needs to be set, but we can't tell without the proper headers.

Comment: Also, `Reply-To:` is a sign of cargo cult programming.  It's not necessary if it's equivalent to `From:`.  But perhaps you should be using a proper email library rather than guessing what the headers should be.